# The one tag cleanup post to rule them all

Tags: discussion, tags

As I went through more and more tags, I found that more than a couple probably need cleaning up. Any tags that you feel need cleaning up - post them as an answer, as they get voted up and down they can be cleaned up.

Up vote = "I agree this tag need cleaning"

Down vote = "I disagree this tag needs cleaning"

No vote = What? No! Voting for the future, make your voice be heard!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do you think it's time for a change in the way we use tags?](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1733/do-you-think-its-time-for-a-change-in-the-way-we-use-tags)

Answer (score 6):

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - Tags [blu-ray](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blu-ray) and [dvd](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dvd) have been removed accordingly.

[blu-ray](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blu-ray)

Not sure we need a tag for a specific HD format, however, the point is moot as pretty much every question with this tag is mistagged and should probably have some kind of "high definition" replacement.

The consensus on this one would probably result in the [dvd](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dvd) tag being nuked also, since it suffers from all of the same problem (including being used in a large amount of instances where it's just not needed)

Comment: Given Blu-ray won the Great Format War, and I can't see why there would be any questions that wouldn't be technical (and therefore suited to other SE sites), I agree there's no need for it or the DVD tag to really exist. I'd also be hesitant to add a [tag:format] tag because that would likely lead people to feel they can ask questions about buying/obtaining movies on a specific format.

Answer (score 3):

The [specific-scene](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-scene) tag looks awfully meta.

I'm not sure that anybody is ever going to use it as a filter without using another tag to go with it (how can you be an expert in 'specific scenes'?)

If we agree to delete it, a mod can just remove the tag (which saves editing anything and rearranging the front page). Does this tag serve a purpose and do we even need it?

Answer (score 2):

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - The [accent](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accent) tag was made a synonym of [dialogue](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialogue).

[accent](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accent)

Probably not required, would be covered by [actor-name](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actor-name) or [dialogue](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialogue) in pretty much every instance you'd ever use it.

Comment: Its in pending tag suggestion for [tag:character] http://movies.stackexchange.com/tags/character/synonyms

Comment: I have removed the one tag that used it, you should probably just synonym it to character

Answer (score 0):

[copyright](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyright) should be merged into [legal](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) - both cover a small number of questions, copyright is a subset of legal and "We're not lawyers" anyway.

Comment: copyright should also be a synonym - its clearly the most commonly asked legal category for us.